# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'powerline_shell'

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I just got Updated with my ubuntu from 19 to 20.04 LTS and 
when i am trying to work in gnome terminal it shows an error

**File "/usr/local/bin/powerline-shell", line 6, in 
    from powerline_shell import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'powerline_shell'.**
What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo pip install powerline-shell` ?

Comment: Ya ,I did that again same error it shows!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### So I got the Solution for my question.

*Type  >* 
**vi .bashrc** in  a **terminal** 
And delete all the codes for ***Powerline-Shell*** .If previously edited. 
Save the file and restart the terminal.